# Angularjs not binding data and html not printing scope variables

Tags: html, angularjs

That's my complete code angular is not printing vars in the body tag of the html pice, console.log() everywhere is working. ng-click at submit button is also working.

```
<html ng-app="fb">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap      /3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-   BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5  /angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-cookie/4.1.0/angular-cookie.js"></script>

<script>
var app=angular.module('fb', []);

app.controller('home',function($scope){
    var hi;
    $scope.hi=5;
    //$rootScope.hola=9;
    console.log($scope.hi);
    //console.log($rootScope.hola);

    $scope.submitSignup=function()
    {
    var hi;
    $scope.hi=5;
    //$rootScope.hola=9;
    console.log($scope.hi);
    //console.log($rootScope.hola);
    console.log($scope.username);
        alert('button pressed');
    };
});

</script>
<head>
<title>Index</title
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller='home'>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
<br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
<br>

<button type="button" ng-click="submitSignup()">SignUp</button>

<br>

<p> {{username}} </p>


<p> {{hi}} </p>


{{hola}}


</div>

<p> index </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Scratching my head for hours and hours at this, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initiate your app with `ng-app="fb"`

```
 <body ng-app="fb">
    <div ng-controller="home">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
        <br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
        <br>
        <button type="button" ng-click="submitSignup()">SignUp</button>

        <p> {{username}} </p>

        <p> {{hi}} </p>

        {{hola}}

    </div>
    <p> index </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ng-app="fb" is added above all sources in the <html> tag.

Comment: Show your files which are loaded in ur above html

Comment: These are the links I had from angular's documentation. Angular is working, but data is not being displayed also ng-click does calls my function and generates alert.

Comment: Try to abstract your angular code into a js and give the reference to that js file in your above html

Comment: that space was added maybe while posting, its not in my source code. Okay going to put it in js file. But it should work this way.

Comment: add type="text/javascript" also in your script tag. And try to bring scripts and styles within  head tag

Comment: Did it, doesn't work. Can you copy the code and run it at your browser?

Comment: This is strange, I think the problem might be with your angular links. Maybe copy all the cdns again and try to copy the same versions for angular angular routing etc?

Answer (score 2):

add ng-app  in your template with **`ng-app="fb"`**

**DEMO**

```html
<html ng-app="fb">
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app=angular.module('fb', []);
app.controller('home',function($scope){
    var hi;
    $scope.hi=5;
    //$rootScope.hola=9;
    console.log($scope.hi);
    //console.log($rootScope.hola);

    $scope.submitSignup=function()
    {
    var hi;
    $scope.hi=5;
    //$rootScope.hola=9;
    console.log($scope.hi);
    //console.log($rootScope.hola);
    console.log($scope.username);
        alert('button pressed');
    };
});
</script>
<body>
<div ng-controller='home'>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
<br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
<br>
<button type="button" ng-click="submitSignup()">SignUp</button>
<br>
<p> {{username}} </p>
<p> {{hi}} </p>
{{hola}}
</div>
<p> index </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ng-app="fb" is added above all sources in the <html> tag.

Comment: did you check the demo? in your html there is no reference for angular and script

Comment: These are the links I have added, ng-click works so angular does work.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-cookie/4.1.0/angular-cookie.js"></script>

Comment: where is the reference for your controller and module script

Comment: they are in the same file so maybe no reference needed?

Comment: the problem is your angular.js reference file. it has a empty space . check the updated demo